# How to set an optional parameter of date/time ssrs parameter along with specifying dataset query of available values in it

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am facing a problem with ssrs report. I want to set an optional parameter of date/time parameter. But besides I want to specify available values to be redirected to other dataset query. Is there any possible way to do it.

Comment: Please try by setting Allow Null for parameter it will execute report without passing any vlaue

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: It's taking values directly from dataset query @kevin

Comment: can you show your query or sample code

Comment: Select period_end_date from periods is the dataset query I have added in parameter period from and period thru

Comment: please edit your question and add anything that is relevant such as the parameters properties, your dataset query(s) including any that are used to populate parameters

Comment: Thanks. Anyway my problem is sorted out by setting out a default value.